# BatchApexErrorEvent not logging error

Tags: apex, batch

I just created a simple batch that gives custom exception when specific condition are met. I am using BatchApexErrorEvent for logging the some random value in account object Phone field to verify how it works. Its not updating the Phone field value, also I can not also see the logs. I have enable the log for Automated Process and also specifically for that trigger.

```
trigger HandleError on BatchApexErrorEvent (after insert) {
    Set<Id> asyncApexJobIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(BatchApexErrorEvent evt:Trigger.new){
        asyncApexJobIds.add(evt.AsyncApexJobId);
    }
    
    Map<Id,AsyncApexJob> jobs = new Map<Id,AsyncApexJob>(
        [SELECT id, ApexClass.Name FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id IN :asyncApexJobIds]
    );
    
    List<Account> records = new List<Account>();
    for(BatchApexErrorEvent evt:Trigger.new){
        //only handle events for the job(s) we care about
            System.debug('Scope'+evt );
            for (String item : evt.JobScope.split(',')) {
                Account a = new Account(
                    Id = (Id)item,
                    Phone='00000'
                );
                records.add(a);
            }
        
    }
    update records;
}
```

```
public class AccountBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.RaisesPlatformEvents{
    public class CustomException extends Exception{}
    
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        return Database.getQueryLocator([select id,billingstate from account]);
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<sobject> scope){
        for(Account acc: (List<Account>)scope){
            if(acc.billingstate == 'OR'){
                throw new CustomException();
            }
            if(acc.billingstate == 'UK'){
                throw new CustomException();
            }
            //do an processing
        }
    }
    public void finish(database.BatchableContext bc){
        
    }
}
```

Comment: does your `start()` method return Accounts with `BillingState` = `OR` or `UK` ?

Comment: IT is throw error, so yes.